# Is there any way to disable android default pop up layout and show a custom layout instead?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I want to change android default volume layout and show a custom animations instead. Is there any feasible solution or any other approach?

[sample image here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZPnE.png)

Answer (score 0):

nope, there is no option for such change

BUT using [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service) you may catch volume button clicks and then draw on screen when [`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission is granted. thats pretty hard task